# Multiple scrape jobs running on same target in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm working on use case where I need to scrape metrics at different scrape intervals. For example, `metric_one` needs to be scraped for every 1 hr and `metric_two` is scraped for every 15s. Both of these metrics are from the same target. The solution that I have tried is following:

```
global:
scrape_interval: 15s
scrape_configs:
 - job_name: 'job_two'
   static_configs:
     - targets:
       - targets: ["engine:5001"]
   metric_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
     regex: 'metric_one'
     action: drop
 - job_name: 'job_one'
   scrape_interval: 3600s
   static_configs:
     - targets:
       - targets: ["engine:5001"]
   metric_relabel_configs:
   - source_labels: [ __name__ ]
     regex: 'metric_two'
     action: drop
```

This Prometheus config tries to run two different scrape jobs on same host. `job_one` only scrapes `metric_one` and `job_two` only scrapes `metric_one`, but the Prometheus service discovery does not work properly with `job_two` and heath-check status is shown `unknown` and sometimes it doesn't appear at all when I run `up` in Prometheus console.
Is there any other proper solution to this or am I doing something wrong in this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to decrease the scrape interval to 5 minutes or less.

This is something like Prometheus internals. ***PromQL only looks back for 5 minutes to find samples***, so after this amount of time since the last scrape you start seeing the described behavior. It is easy to see on a graph, you will quickly notice that the metric like breaks shortly after the last scrape. In order to prevent this, you need to scrape the metric at least every five minutes, even if the metric value does not change that often. This is just to tell Prometheus that the metric is still there.