# How to write an alert for data exposed by blackbox exporter?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have `probe_success{job="my_service"}` that is generated every 1 hour by blackbox exporter and it's either 0 or 1.

What's the correct expression to generate an alert?

Is `probe_success{job="my_service"} == 0` correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression-wise `probe_success == 0` or `probe_success != 1` are valid choices.

However, **you made it so** that the metric appears only **once in an hour** which makes it impossible to use with the `for` alert parameter. In other words, your alert will only work without `for` and with that you will have all sorts of false alarms because of network glitches and other short random events.

If you want to use `for`, then you should set the scrape interval for the job to **at least 5 minutes**.

Comment: Thanks, why 5 minutes though? could I settle on let's say 15m?

Comment: I don't think I need the `for` though. I just want to make an alert once a `0` is seen. What would happen (by default) if there were let's say 3 consecutive `0` in a row? Would we see 3 alerts?

Comment: @sleekster metrics disappear if not updated within 5 minutes (https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107940/11344502). With this setup you will have what you want, meaning that the alert will fire on any failure, but: 1) alert will resolve itself after 5 minutes; 2) short outages might go unnoticed (e.g. server crashed and was down for 55 minutes then went back online before the health check).